# How to get dialog box to prompt user to change the "format text" to HTML when pasting a picture in email reply?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, html, dialog, plaintext

I used to be able to use the Ctrl + V to paste a picture in an email that I was reading in the preview pane and replying from that preview pane. I would get this pop-up message that would ask if I would like to switch the format of the email reply to HTML and I would click "switch to HTML" and it would then allow me to paste items that required the email to be in HTML format.

Last time I clicked no and checked the dialog box "don't ask me again" accidentally and now I can't figure out how to turn that back on so it will prompt me and allow this type of format so I can paste pictures and excel tables in the email reply.

I can still change the format if I use the "pop-out message" and then open a full blown reply window and then I can select the "format text" menu and then select "HTML" in the format group.

[image: Image of dialogue]
[image]

Comment: Please refer to this article: https://www.msoutlook.info/question/190

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I tried as suggested by Aidan in the comments.
We need to remove the key name 'SettingsWordMail' at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office<version>\Word\Data by accessing it through Regedit.

Do that while closing the Outlook and after removing the value, open the Outlook, the popup to switch to the HTML is back when trying to paste the image.